# Simple mail send on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, smtp

I have been struggling with mail function in Ubuntu. My goal is to send a test email from a terminal with a command:

```
echo "msg" | mail -s subject sample@domain.com.
```

I have tried to install `sendmail`, but figured out that it could send if I rely on rely server(google smtp). I have tried to install `exim4`, but in logs provides this data:

```
2015-11-10 19:09:03 1ZwCPm-00015C-TP <= root@localhost U=root P=local S=788  
2015-11-10 19:09:03 1ZwCPm-00015C-TP ** localhost@localdomain <root@localhost>: Unrouteable address  
2015-11-10 19:09:03 1ZwCPm-00015C-TP => /var/mail/mail (root@localhost) <root@localhost> R=mail4root T=address_file 

2015-11-10 19:09:03 1ZwCPn-00015H-4o <= <> R=1ZwCPm-00015C-TP U=Debian-exim P=local S=1607 

2015-11-10 19:09:03 1ZwCPm-00015C-TP Completed
```

I have no experience before configuring mail servers. Is it possible to do such action without having FQDN and domain name? Where do I start my investigation on such topic?

Answer (score 1):

Install the `postfix` package and edit your configuration (usually at `/etc/postfix/main.cf`) to be:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
```

Now, create the `/etc/postfix/sasl` directory and create a file called `passwd` inside with this content:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    your_username@gmail.com:PASSWORD
```

Finally, use this command:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
```

Now, if you use the first syntax (which was correct), you should get your e-mail sent:

```
echo "msg" | mail -s subject sample@domain.com.
```

Comment: Is this possible if I don't want to rely on relayhost?

Comment: `relayhost` is the host through which you will send your messages. If you don't want to use a Gmail account, you'll need to specify a different provider and configure your client so it will allow you sending e-mails.

Comment: I cannot create my own host?

Comment: Sure, for that you should configure your own e-mail server. For allowing it to work correctly, you should use a real DNS host so your outgoing e-mails are not marked as spam. You can start here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot